# Trying to append data to google sheets via google sheets API in Python

Tags: python, api, google-sheets

My intentions are to put the data extracted from places API into google sheets.
I have followed a lot of methods including using gspread library and making a service account and then authorizing it.

I am currently trying with the service account where I have passed on the credentials, built a service request, and then executed it. However, it is throwing me the following error `Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name`

What am I doing wrong?

I wanted to append data in google sheets but I am getting an error.

## Code

```
from __future__ import print_function

import requests
import urllib.parse as urlparse
from googleapiclient import discovery
import os.path
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError


SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file']

# The ID and range of a sample spreadsheet.
SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID = '1_oKFw7gYmUWDUZxZ6Dgo1uLM9Tf_Bc-4bnq4jiJbQUs'
SAMPLE_RANGE_NAME = 'Sheet1'
creds = None

if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            'credentials.json', SCOPES)
        creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
    # Save the credentials for the next run
    with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
        token.write(creds.to_json())
        
spreadsheet_id = '***************'
range_ = 'Sheet1!'
value_input_option = 'RAW'        



service = discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)


value_range_body = ['a']


request = service.spreadsheets().values().append(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, range=range_,                
valueInputOption=value_input_option, body=value_range_body)
response = request.execute()
```

## Error

> <HttpError 400 when requesting
> https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1_oKFw7gYmUWDUZxZ6Dgo1uLM9Tf_Bc-4bnq4jiJbQUs/values/Sheet1%21:append?valueInputOption=RAW&alt=json returned "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "": Root element
> must be a message.". Details: "[{'@type':
> 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest', 'fieldViolations':
> [{'description': 'Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "": Root
> element must be a message.'}]}]">

Comment: I would remove the spreadsheet ID for security reasons

Comment: @BlueRobin, I added a sample code. I hope it helps. Let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 1):

The error is related to how `value_range_body` is parse. If you want to use the method [spreadsheets.values.append](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append), you can base you code in the following sample:

*Note: the sample code that I'm using is base on a database, and using OAuth, but the request body should be the same*

```
from __future__ import print_function

import os.path

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError



# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file', 
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets' ]

# The ID and range of a sample spreadsheet.
spreadsheetId = 'sheetID'




def main():

    creds = None

    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    try:
        service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
        # 'records_df' is the variable with the data that will be inserted in the Sheet. 
        # In your case it will be the data coming from places API
        records_db = [['2023-01-18', '1234', 'ABC', 1234], 
                      ['2023-01-17', '5678', 'DEF', 5678], 
                      ['2023-01-16', '9012', 'ABC', 9012]]

        # 'range_db' is the range of the where the data will be added.
        range_db = "Sheet1"
        value_input_option = "RAW"
        insert_data_option = "INSERT_ROWS"

        # This is the 'value_range_body' or JSON
        value_range_body = {
                        "majorDimension": "ROWS",
                        "values": records_db,
                        }

        request = service.spreadsheets().values().append(spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId, 
                                                         range=range_db, 
                                                         valueInputOption=value_input_option, 
                                                         insertDataOption=insert_data_option, 
                                                         body=value_range_body)
        response = request.execute()

    except HttpError as err:
        print(err)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```